# Android achartengine doughnut chart

Tags: java, android, achartengine

Hi all I am trying to reduce the inner radius of doughnut chart in Android development by using `achartengine`. I declared my chart layout as such:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/doughtnut_chart"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, I customized the renderer by using this:

```
renderer.setScale((float)1.4);
```

However, the radius of the circle is not reducing. I can't find any solution online either.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `renderer.setScale()` is the correct API to use for reducing the size, the parameter should probably be something smaller than `1`.

Once done this, just call `mChartView.repaint()` in order to do the visual refresh, in case you are modifying the size during runtime.

Comment: Can you help me in adding two charts in the same activity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48670479/android-layout-issue-unable-to-add-two-layouts-of-two-charts-using-addview-log?noredirect=1#comment84338852_48670479